# Improve entity input performance with many results Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have a form with an **entity input field** that load a deployable *(select - option)* with **120000 results**. Render this makes the page take up to **30 seconds** to load.

Do you know any other way to handle this type of control forms in symfony to not take so long to load?

The form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('contact', 'text', array(
            'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('address', 'text')
    ->add('id_spanish_town', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PanelBundle:SpanishTowns',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('z')
                ->orderBy('z.name', 'asc');
            }
    ))
    ->add('password', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'first_name' => 'pass',
            'second_name' => 'pass_confirm',
            'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('email', 'email', array(
            'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('about_us', 'textarea', array(
            'required' => false
    ))
    ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Save'
    ));
}
```

**Greetings and thank you.**

Comment: You could try caching, and also fetching the entities without hydrating them, with a direct query just for the needed field (ID and a description for the select)

Comment: No one in the whole world is waiting to make a selection out of 120.000 choices. Instead you could use jquery's autocomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing select of all products, I'd use some item suggestion and ajax/json provider with limit to ~15 items.

We have around 60 000 products and it would collapse database for such a huge selection.

The `QueryBuilder` in simplified version:

```
// ...

/**
 * @var int
 */
const ITEMS_LIMIT = 15;


public function getDataForResponse($entityName, $name)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('e.id, e.name')
        ->from($entityName, 'e');
        ->where('e.name LIKE :name')
        ->setParameter('name', '%' . $name . '%');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
        ->setMaxResults(self::ITEMS_LIMIT)
        ->getResult(Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at selectize.js for the ClientSide